# How to Capture On-Screen Keyboard Keystrokes and Redirect to External Window like Notepad

Tags: python, on-screen-keyboard

everyone! I need some help. I am building an on-screen keyboard, and I want it so that when I click on a button, it writes that button's keystroke to another window, such as Notepad, instead of the GUI text box.

I have following code of GUI

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def btn_clicked_keyboard():
    kb = tk.Tk()

    buttons = [
    'ESC', '~', '`', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '+', 'ENTER',
    'TAB', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '\\', '/', '1', '2', '3','BACKSPACE',
    '.com', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', '[', ']', '=', '4', '5', '6', 'SPACE',
    'SHIFT','z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '?', '{', '}', '7', '8', '9', '0',
    ]

    def select(value):
        if value == "ESC":
            entry.delete(1.0,tk.END)
        elif value == "SPACE":
            entry.insert(tk.END, ' ')
        elif value == "BACKSPACE":
            if len(entry.get(1.0,tk.END))<=1:
                new=""
            else:
                new = entry.get(1.0,tk.END)[:-2]
            entry.delete(1.0,tk.END)
            entry.insert(tk.END, new)
        elif value == "TAB":
            entry.insert(tk.END, '    ')
        elif value == "ENTER":
            entry.insert(tk.END, '\n')
        else :
            entry.insert(tk.END,value)

    def HosoPop():

        varRow = 3
        varColumn = 0

        for button in buttons:

            command = lambda x=button: select(x)

            if button == "SPACE" or button == "SHIFT" or button == "BACKSPACE" or button == "ENTER" or button == "ESC" or button == ".com" or button == "0" or button == "TAB":
                tk.Button(kb,text= button,width=16, height=2, bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff",
                    activebackground = "#ffffff", activeforeground="#000000", relief='raised', padx=1,
                    pady=1, bd=1,command=command).grid(row=varRow,column=varColumn)

            else:
                tk.Button(kb,text= button,width=8,height=2, bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff",
                    activebackground = "#ffffff", activeforeground="#000000", relief='raised', padx=1,
                    pady=1, bd=1,command=command).grid(row=varRow,column=varColumn)


            varColumn +=1 

            if varColumn > 16 and varRow == 3:
                varColumn = 0
                varRow+=1
            if varColumn > 16 and varRow == 4:
                varColumn = 0
                varRow+=1
            if varColumn > 16 and varRow == 5:
                varColumn = 0
                varRow+=1



    kb.title("VIRTUAL KEYBOARD GUI")
    kb.resizable(0,0)


    label1 = tk.Label(kb,text='      VIRTUAL KEYBOARD         ').grid(row=0,columnspan=17)

    entry =tk.Text(kb, width=106,height=10,font=("arial",15,"bold"),wrap=tk.WORD)
    entry.grid(row=1,columnspan=17)
    label2 = tk.Label(kb,text='               ').grid(row=2,columnspan=17)
    # entry.pack()
    HosoPop()

    kb.mainloop()
    
    
btn_clicked_keyboard()
```

I attempted to capture keystrokes from an on-screen keyboard within my GUI application. I expected that when I clicked on a button on the on-screen keyboard, the corresponding keystroke would be sent to another window, such as Notepad, for example. . Thank you